# How can we search the json file based on date field using S3 select

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I am trying to query data on JSON file using S3-Select. I am unable to filter based on the date field. I have tried using current_date, sysdate and a few CAST options too. I am planning to compute the curent_date and send it from API. Before that, I wanted to check if there was any other way to get the current date in the query.

Sample Json :

[image]

S3 Select Queries I have tried :

```
select * from S3Object[*].stations[*] as station where station.iataCd = 'NCL' and station.expiryDt >= sysdate();
select * from S3Object[*].stations[*] as station where station.iataCd = 'NCL' and station.expiryDt >= current_date;
select * from S3Object[*].stations[*] as station where station.iataCd = 'NCL' and station.expiryDt >= '2023-01-23'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current UTC timestamp with `UTCNOW()` date function, if that is what you want

> [UTCNOW()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-date.html#s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-utcnow)  gives you current UTC time  as timestamp: `2017-10-13T16:02:11.123Z`